# SAS proc report Order after Group

Tags: sas, proc-report

I am new user of SAS and trying proc report,

```
filename exer2 '~/201207Hac.csv';
data work.exercise2;
    infile exer2 dlm="," firstobs=2;
    input Type $ Region $ Country $ City $ Imp Exp Ts; 
run;

proc report data = work.exercise2 nowd headline headskip;
    where type = "M";
    column Region Imp;
    define Region / group 'REGION'; 
run;
```

The output has two column with REGION and corresponding sum of Imp value.

 I wanna try `define Imp / Order;` but fail.

While i would like to sort the imp descendingly. How can i achieve that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well you have a couple of easy options.

First is to do a proc sort before the proc report:

```
PROC SORT DATA = work.exercise2; BY DESCENDING Imp; RUN;
```

Or you can order the proc report:

```
proc report data = work.exercise2 nowd headline headskip;
    where type = "M";
    column Region Imp / order order=data descending;
    define Region / group 'REGION'; 
run;
```

Comment: Hi @jj72uk, for the second option. there is syntax error for /. I m not sure whether it is because i am using university edition?

Comment: @useR which version of SAS do you have? Help > About

Comment: @useR I'm not familiar with SAS Studio. The example of using 'ORDER' is syntax-ly correct as I can use it on BASE SAS. Try my first option, proc sorting the dataset before proc reporting.

Comment: ask one more quesiton. how can i achieve this by proc print ?

Comment: @useR Consider this example of sorting then using proc print: `data need;
 set sashelp.class;
run;
proc print data = need; run;
proc sort data=need out=want_sorted;
 by age;
run;
proc print data = want_sorted; run;`